# How to inherit property annotations in Mapped Types with key remapping?

Tags: typescript, types, annotations, jsdoc

Following the [Key Remapping example on the typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), is there a way to inherit property annotations of the initial Type ?

```js
type Prefix<Type, str extends string> = {
    [Property in keyof Type as `${str}${Capitalize<string & Property>}`]: Type[Property]
};
 
interface Person {
    /** This is the name. */
    name: string;

    /** This is the age. */
    age: number;

    /** This is the location. */
    location: string;
}
 
interface A extends Prefix<Person, 'alpha'>, Prefix<Person, 'beta'> {};
```

Hovering `A.alphaName`, I would like the editor to show `(property) A.alphaName: string. This is the name.` by default and overwrite only necessary annotations ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a missing feature of TypeScript reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#50715](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50715).  Currently [key-remapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) types don't preserve [JSDoc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/intro-to-js-ts.html#providing-type-hints-in-js-via-jsdoc) comments.  The issue is open and marked as "[Help Wanted](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/labels/Help%20Wanted)", meaning that interested community members are invited to [submit pull requests](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7bee9c55b1b90a7711c8a635dfc6de102ab069fe/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-bug-fixes) to address it.  So if you want to see this happen, you might want to make it happen yourself!